# Правильное использование свойств C#

Tags: c#, properties, property, свойства

Часто вижу разную реализацию одного и того же простого кода

```
// 1
private int _health;
public int Health { get => _health; }
```

```
// 2 
public int Health { get; private set; }
```

По сути, это одно и то же? Стоит ли использовать что-то конкретное или никакой разницы нет?

Comment: Вроде да, просто автоматические свойства хоть и давно появились, но всё же не сразу, возможно первый код писали до их появления, да так и осталось.

Comment: Разница в том, что в первом случае есть прямой доступ к приватному полю, который желательно не иметь. Во втором случае к автосгененированному приватному полю доступ только через свойство - что и является назначением свойств - инкапсулировать доступ. Предпочтение по умолчанию второму варианту, первый использовать только если есть какая то причина для этого.

Comment: @tym32167 а в первом сет не добавлен, его сеттировать можно? И ещё, как понять фразу ---доступ через свойство(что там свойство -гет?)

Comment: Нельзя )  Имеется в виду на установку значения. В первом варианте явно через переменную, это плохо. Хотя во втором варианте сеттер всё-равно без внутренней логики, и в обоих вариантах доступ к установке значения только изнутри класса, так что на мой взгляд разница не сильно большая

Comment: Не одно и то же, в одном случае сеттер есть, в другом - нет.

Comment: Придерживайтесь одного простого правила: Если поле необходимо для расширения логики свойства, то делайте его, ну а если нет, оно бесполезно и даже вредно (как минимум код становиться менее логичным). Вот самое просто, вы в `set` допустим хотите добавить логику, пишете `int Value { get; set {SomeMethod(); ...} }`, понимаете, что без поля вам не решить задачу, вам нужно полностью раскрывать свойство, переписывая геттер и сеттер. Вот только там, где он необходим, ему и место.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Работать с полем, логически выделенном для публикации через свойство (backing field) за пределами геттера и сеттера - плохой тон, усложняющий отладку кода и увеличивающий вероятность появления ошибок.

Если свойство неизменяемое, то это должно быть видно сразу, например должен отсутствовать сеттер.

Технически разницы между полными и автосвойствами никакой нет. Для автосвойства поле выделит компилятор.

Answer (score 1):

Да, это одно и то же. Разницы быть не должно и при оптимизирующей компиляции.

Второй вариант выглядит более предпочтительным.

Разница может появиться, если вместо типа int (а в общем же вопрос не ограничивается одним типом) будет структура. Тогда в первом случае можно будет менять структуру через поле, а во втором - нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

1. В версиях языка до С#6 отсутствовала возможность указать инициализатор для auto-implemented properties, поэтому им приходилось всегда задавать начальное значение в конструкторе либо (в случае свойств только для чтения), делать `readonly` поле с инициализацией в конструкторе и отдельно свойство для чтения. В C#6 этот недостаток устранили и появилась возможность указывать инициализатор
   `public int Health { get; private set; } = 42;`
2. auto-implemented properties не могут быть использованы при создании классов с явно заданным распределением памяти, так как для них нельзя указать обязательный атрибут смещения данных:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size=16, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
class MyClass
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]public ushort first;
    [FieldOffset(2)]public ushort second;
    // ok
    [FieldOffset(4)]private int _health; 
    public int Health { get => _health; }
    // error FieldOffset не применим
    [FieldOffset(4)]public int Health { get; private set; }
    // error отсутствует обязательный FieldOffset
    public int Health { get; private set; }
}
```